# How to use ASP.Net MVC5 scaffolding list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

This may be simple question for experts, since I am learning ASP.NET MVC I am facing issues, and I am facing trouble in searching in google for framing the question.

1. I am trying to bind grid in Asp.Net MVC and crud operations.
2. While selecting list in scaffolding I am able to bind the grid (is it really grid, if I want to loop through this how to do this?)

Let me show my code.

Model :

```
namespace JsonResultTest.Models
{
    public class Model
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Amount{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    static List<Model> lstBond = new List<Model>
    {
        new Model{Number="123456789-99",Id="987654321",Address="155 The Terrace,Weelington 6011,Newzeland",Amount="NZD,1000"},
        new Model{  Number="123456789-99",Id="987654321",Address="155 The Terrace,Weelington 6011,Newzeland",Amount="NZD,1000"},                               
    };

// GET: ShoppingBasket
public ActionResult BindGrid()
{
    return View(lstBond);
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<JsonResultTest.Models.Model>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>BasketGrid</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>

                <input type="checkbox" name="deleteInputs" />
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="deleteInputs" />


            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Issues is: I am able to bind data to this grid, but there is an amount column in the grid. Based on the selected check boxes, I have to add the amount and have to display the amount in label.

I am looking for sample for the below.

1. if I select top check box all the check box in the grid should enable
2. Only enabled check boxes amount has to be summed off.

Since I am very beginning, I am trying with in built scaffolding, not third party grids

Can anybody suggest the changes or proper links to achive this functionality?

Comment: You will need javascript/jquery to handle client side events

Comment: @stephen: to play with this grid, could you provide any samples or links, since i am very beginner, while searching in google for the sample, only crud operations i am finding , these kind of samples i am not getting.

Comment: Far too broad (and unclear) as it stands. But you use of the `<input type="checkbox" name="deleteInputs" />` makes no sense. What is the point of just updating the display - your not saving any data and everthing is lost as soon as your navigate away - so its unclear what your really trying to do.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: <input type="checkbox" name="deleteInputs" /> is in the grid header,  if user check that box means ( in the grid items all the check boxes has to be enabled) and for the amount coloumn values has to be added for all. if user selects only couple of check boxes then the corresponding amount has to be summed and need to display in some label, it is the design given by user.

Comment: By _enabled_ I assume you mean _checked_. Start by giving your top checkbox an `id` attrbute (say `id="all"`) and the ones in each row a class name (say `class="item"`) and delete the `name` attribute. To get you started (using jquery) - `$('#all').click(function() { $('.item').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked')); });`

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rooadpae/1/) for an example of what you could do.